# How to nest countif function in Excel? (AND BLANK)

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have an excel sheet that has 2 column, Start (A) and End (B). I would like to count how many occurance of a certain date **and** no End date. How can I nest the `count(if...)` function?

This is what I have so far: `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A999, "4/13")` but I don't know how to do `AND COLUMN B == BLANK`. Thank you.

```
Start   End
4/13    4/13
4/13    5/13
4/13    
4/13    
4/13    
4/13    
4/13    
4/13    
4/13    5/13
4/13    4/13
4/13    4/13
4/13    
4/13    4/13
4/13    4/13
4/13    5/13
4/13    4/13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel 2007 and higher:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A17,"4/13",B2:B17,"")
```

Excel 2003 and lower:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A17=--"4/13/2014"),--(B2:B17=""))
```

Comment: Does the `--` has meanings to it?

Comment: It converts boolean or represented values to their integer counterparts so that the sumproduct can produce correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNTIFS`

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A999, "4/13",Sheet1!B2:B999,"")
```

or SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A2:A999="4/13")*(Sheet1!B2:B999=""))
```